# How to remove rows from a data table when the column headings are year labels

Tags: r, data.table, filtering

I have a data table with column headings as years, for example

> head(gsdb_crossTab)

```
CONS_ID_URN     2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017
0TBX58            9   11   13   12   12   12   12    2
1                 2    4    1    0    0    0    0    0
1000000           0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
1000007           1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0
1000009           0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
1000010           0    1    1    0    1    0    0    1

class(gsdb_crossTab)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

If I try and remove rows in column 2010 with a value of zero
with

```
dummy=gsdb_crossTab["2010">0]
```

then I still find dummy contains rows in column 2010 with rows equal containing zeros.

However:  if I rename the column using

```
setnames(gsdb_crossTab, "2010", "FRED")
```

and then perform the filter

```
gsdb_crossTab <- gsdb_crossTab[FRED>0]
```

then I get the result I expect.

My question is: please could somebody suggest a way to perform this operation
without renaming the column to FRED i.e. using the column label "2010"?

Thank you,

Phil,

Comment: Use the `$` operator, if the colname is "2012" then it should work like this: gsdb_crossTab[gsdb_crossTab$`2012`>0,], make sure to add hyphens to the year, using `$` should automatically detect the variable though

Comment: @timfaber, I think that will return 
`Error: unexpected numeric constant in "gsdb_crossTab $2010"`

Comment: hence the hyphen remark :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use back quote (I cannot put this in the comment as it uses grave accents)

```
dummy <- gsdb_crossTab[`2010` > 0]
```